# Object-to-bytes conversion

Tags: c#, .net, conventions

When I'm trying to convert an object into byte array I'm getting a wierd array.
this is the code:

```
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(ms.ToArray()));
        }
//int obj = 50;

//string ByteArrayToString(byte[] byteArr) the functionality of this method is pretty obvious
```

the result is this:

"00 01 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 01 00 00 00 0C 53 79 73 74 65 6D 2E 49 6E 74 33 32 01 00 00 00 07 6D 5F 76 61 6C 75 65 00 08 32 00 00 00 0B "

Can somebody explain to me WHY?:) the  optimal result should be only "32 00 00 00".

Comment: This is exactly what I would expect to happen. You are converting the `MemortyStream` object instead of integer variable `obj`to a `byte` array. There is a `integer` to `Byte[]` I suggest you use it.  I have to vote this question down since it seems like you spent no time trying to figure it out.

Comment: @Ramhound: your explanation makes no sense as the OP is clearly *not* serializing the `MemoryStream`. Please refer to [`BinaryFormatter.Serialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5sbs8z9.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since serializer needs to provide enough information to deserialize the data back, it must include some metadata about the object being serialized. Specifically, the

```
53 79 73 74 65 6D 2E 49 6E 74 33 32
```

part stands for `System.Int32`

If you use [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) and its `Write(Int32)` method instead, you'll get the desired effect: your memory stream will contain just the four bytes from your integer. You wouldn't be able to deserialize it without knowing that you wrote an `Int32` into the stream.

Comment: +1, I think the OP is a bit fuzzy on the purpose of Serialization.

Comment: Hmm, what if I don't know the exactly type of 'obj' at compile time? Because I am actually using it to convert an Object object that represents another type (which known only at runtime)ץ

Comment: @TalBin Then you need to include *some* information to identify that object's type to the code that converts the binary data back to an object. It does not necessarily need to be the data provided by the binary formatter - you can invent your own scheme - but it needs to be there. For example, if you know that all you can pass around is either an int, a string, or a double, you can prefix an extra byte to your data, and set it to 1 if the rest is a string, 2 id the rest is an int, and 3 if the rest is a double. The details are entirely up to you, but some info needs to be there.

Answer (score 2):

You're conflating `BinaryFormatter` serialization with an object's *in memory format*. What is written to the stream is merely an implementation detail of the `BinaryFormatter` and should not be relied upon for any interprocess communication not using `BinaryFormatter`.

If you're looking for the byte representation of the built-in types, use [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes.aspx) (for strings use the appropriate [`Encoding.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

The serialized byte array has both the data itself and the type info. That's why you get more info than you expect. That's neccessary for later deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

The extra stuff in the results would be the BinaryFormatter object.  You're not just outputting int obj = 50, you're outputting everything included in the BinaryFormatter as well.

Comment: -1, no the memory stream is what is being *written to* not what is being sent to the stream.

Comment: Right, misspoke, meant to type BinaryFormatter and got distracted.

Comment: To clarify, the *extra stuff* is an implementation detail of binary serialization. It enables a `BinaryFormatter` to deserialize the object graph correctly. It isn't actually the `BinaryFormatter` instance itself being serialized alongside the object, but metadata about the number and types of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization process uses extra bytes to store information about types - it's the only way to ensure that serialized data will be deserialized into same objects of same types.
If you absolutely sure in what you doing and want to avoid any extra bytes, you may use your own serialization and make your formatter and serializers, which is very complicated. Or, you could use marshalling:

```
var size = Marshal.SizeOf(your_object);
// Both managed and unmanaged buffers required.
var bytes = new byte[size];
var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
// Copy object byte-to-byte to unmanaged memory.
Marshal.StructureToPtr(font.LogFont, ptr, false);
// Copy data from unmanaged memory to managed buffer.
Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, size);
// Release unmanaged memory.
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

And to convert bytes to object:

```
var bytes = new byte[size];
var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, size);
var your_object = (YourType)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(YourType));
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

This is quite slow and unsafe to use in most cases, but it's easiest way to strictly convert object to byte[] without implementing serialization and without [Serializable] attribute.